# MySQL connection pooling and creating temporary table

Tags: mysql, grails, connection-pooling, temp-tables

I already set up MySQL connection pool in Glassfish using JNDI. I only execute one query at a time but use the same sql instance. Everything seems to work fine except creating temporary tables and use them. In short, even though after I create a temporary table, insert query does not work since the table does not exist. Are there any configurations I might look into? Is it possible to create temp table and use it within multiple statements.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This works fine in Java.  It's from Groovy/Grails that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary tables are only available within the connection/session you created them in.  You can use them within multiple statements, but you can't switch to another connection in the pool and expect the temporary table to be there.